# Two jQuery object conflict

Tags: jquery, tabs, slider, conflict

I'm having this problem, I can't get to work two jQuery based objects on my page. According to placement, on or other doesn't seem to work properly.

Codes looks about this at the moment :

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sprinkle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                generateNextPrev: false
            });
        });

    </script>
```

I'm out of options, any ideas how to get these guys to work together?

Comment: You mean you are having problems with the fact that you have included jQuery twice in your page?  Why are you doing this?

Comment: I must be tired as hell to not to notice this. Everything works fine thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're really not supposed to use two `jQuery` versions together at the same time, but if you must:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $jq1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $jq2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now you have the `1.2.6` version as `$jq1` and the other as `$jq2`:

```
$jq1(function(){
        $jq1('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            generateNextPrev: false
        });
    });
```