# Two jQuery scripts conflict on the same page

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with putting two jQuery scripts on the same page, what should I do?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slidepanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-slidepanel]').slidepanel( {
            orientation: 'left',
            mode: 'push'
        });
    });

</script>
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#Grid').mixitup();
    });
</script>
```

I know jQuery.noConflict() may solve this problem, but I don't know how to apply it to this. Any help?

Comment: Why are you loading the jQuery twice? What does jQuery 1.9.1 support that 1.9.0 doesn't?

Comment: You should only need one copy of JQuery. I can't imagine 1.9.0 differs enough from 1.9.1 that you need to include both. Take out the older version and you'll probably find it working just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two jQuery object conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593753/two-jquery-object-conflict)

Comment: Even take out the 1.9.0, still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You only want one copy of jQuery, as everyone is saying. Using the Google CDN as you do is advisable, as explained [here](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).
2. If it's still not working, try each element of your code separately. So reformat your code like this. You'll note I've added `type="text/javascript"` for one of the scripts.

> ```
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slidepanel.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script> 
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     (function($){ // Self-executing wrapper that sets $=jQuery
>         $(function() { // Fires onload
>             $('[data-slidepanel]').slidepanel( {
>                 orientation: 'left',
>                 mode: 'push'
>             });
>             $('#Grid').mixitup();
>         });
>     }(jQuery));
> </script>
> ```

Then try commenting out the two `$('...` statements and see if one or both work.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need two jQuery libraries anyway?! Just use the newer one!
... Let's even say you needed the old one because you need some functions that aren't available in the new framework. Just look them up in search mode and copy past them one by one to the new framework (can only be done if you use jQuery offline like me, which saves loading time during developpement cause it gets cached.)
P.S: I hope this doesn't cause any copyrights infrigments :/

Comment: It's fine to copy jQuery - no copyright infringements. Here's an article why CDN is preferable, though: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 1):

delete old and use this version http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
Rmove old version like
jquery-1.5.2.js and jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: Does this add anything to previous answers?